# automatically redirect user to login page using error code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http-status-codes

I have several web services that are being called using AJAX requests from Asp.Net page. If the user's authorization fails, i want to redirect him to the login page.

The problem i am facing is i have to manually redirect the user in the errorHandler function of AJAX request.

I was wondering if there is a way i can throw HttpException with proper error code from my webserivce (i dont know which) so that browser understands the response and redirects user to the login page?

I tried `throw new HttpException(401,"Unauthorized access request);` in my service call, but my errorHandler handles this exception  and browser doesnt redirect user back to login page.

Also i was thinking if i can achieve this using HttpModule, will that be a better solution rather than having Authorization check in the service constructor?

--Update--

After adding `HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation =  "login.aspx";` and         `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 307;`, it now gives me an error saying `"Resource cannot be found"`. This is what it shows in the RequestedURL: `/Web/Services/svcSomething.asmx/login.aspx`.

How do i tell browser that redirect location is a new page and not the webmethod?

Comment: Hwo about a [`307`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) - Temporary Redirect code.

Comment: well, still browser doesnt redirect user to the login page. it shows the alert i have in the errorHandler.

Answer (score 1):

IMO - you need to handle the error (401) on the server side & redirect the user to the login page. Since you don't have any handler on the server side, the error is passed on to the client as a response & so you are seeing the code on the client-side to redirect the user...